# Is there a way to see the program counter in NetBeans debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

Is there a way to see the line/method that's currently executing in the NetBeans debugger, without doing step-by-step execution?

I know I could set breakpoints, but I'm curious if there's a way to do it without breakpoints.

Comment: You can see this in `VisualVM` by looking at the Threads tab. This allows you to see stack dumps of individual threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), which comes bundled with java JDK, can show you live trackable method executions.

Answer (score 1):

From the right border of the code editor, you should see a lot of colored short lines (which indicate warnings, errors, searches etc), among them there is an line with an small green box in the middle of the line, click it and you will locate the program counter.

The line is small so not easy to click.

In most IDEs, there is a tool bar button and menu to locate current executing line.

Answer (score 0):

@Leon is showing how to locate the current position of the *caret*, which does not necessarily coincide with the program counter.

In the right border of the code editor, there are, indeed, small colored lines (which indicate lines where there are warnings, errors, breakpoints, etc.), among which is one line with a small box in its middle. But it shows the *line where the **caret** happens to be located*.

This is *not necessarily* the location of the program counter because the caret position may have changed since reaching the last breakpoint or other line of code.

The program counter being represented by a (too-small) green block arrow in the left margin of the code editor, where a breakpoint symbol and others can further obfuscate it, no amount of enlarging the editor window contents will make it significantly easier to find the program counter.

[image]

Of course, the program counter will change to where it will be visible by stepping out of,  into, or over whatever's at the current program counter line. This isn't ideal. And there's a better way.

**`Alt+Shift+9`** will open the `Debugging` window (below), which will show a number that represents the *line number of the* ***program counter***.

[image]

Moreover, an expanded `+` dropdown indicator will show a line containing the same pertinent info, but *double-clicking* this line will *open the window containing the program counter and clearly enough show it*.

At least that's my experience so far.